# Submit a form only when data is entered in a form in Angular

Tags: angular

I have created a simple form for getting data from user,
I want to activate the submit button only when one of the input field has data in it.
here is my code:

HTML:

`
    
      Contract No.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Instance No.</mat-label>
  <input matInput id="instanceno" placeholder="" name="instanceno" formControlName="instanceno">
    </mat-form-field>
    <div *ngIf="form.get('instanceno').hasError('pattern')" class="error">Only Numeric Value Allowed
   </div>
    <br>

    <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Serial No.</mat-label>
    <input matInput id="serialno" placeholder=""name="serialno" formControlName="serialno">
    </mat-form-field>
    <br>

    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Customer No.</mat-label>
      <input matInput id="customerno" name="customerno" placeholder="" formControlName="customerno">
    </mat-form-field>
     <br>

  <button mat-button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid" matDialogClose >Submit</button>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
```

`

TS:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
    contractno: new FormControl(''),
    serialno: new FormControl(''),
  instanceno: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern('[0-9]*')),
    customerno: new FormControl('')
  });
```

Comment: So if any one of `contractno`, `serialno`, `instanceno`, `customerno` have at least one character, you want to enable the button? And when they are all length 0 you want to disable the button?

Comment: yes, exactly.
atleast one of the field should have a value

Comment: @IshankJain everything should get a  `Validators.required` . 

take a look at [Reactive form validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)

Comment: @Luxusproblem that would mean that *all* fields must have at least one character. The question is about checking whether *at least* one field has at least one character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach to this would be to store the form controls in a structure that makes it simple to check their values every time the form changes.

Instead of building the form inline, I would store the form controls themselves in separate variables.

```js
form: FormGroup;

private formControls: {
  contractno: FormControl;
  serialno: FormControl;
  instanceno: FormControl;
  customerno: FormControl;
};
private formControlsArray: FormControl[];

ngOnInit() {    
  this.formControls = {
    contractno: new FormControl(''),
    serialno: new FormControl(''),
    instanceno: new FormControl('', Validators.pattern('[0-9]*')),
    customerno: new FormControl('')
  };

  this.formControlsArray = Object.keys(this.formControls)
    .map(key => this.formControls[key]);

  this.form = new FormGroup(this.formControls);
}
```

And then subscribe to the form value changes, checking the form controls array for the existence of a valid value every time the form changes.

```js
hasValue = false;
private destroyed$ = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {    
  // build the form here

  this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
  ).subscribe(() => {
    this.hasValue = this.formControlsArray.some(x => x.value.length > 0);
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroyed$.next();
}
```

Then you can bind your button's `disabled` state to the `hasValue` property.

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <!-- the form -->
  <button [disabled]="!hasValue">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

So if you want to tighten the value checks to, say, only treat non-whitespace values as valid, you can just update this one function.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-array-template-fxxvir